# How to store nested relational data in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm trying to store data within Solr so that I can best maintain the indexes. The problem i'm having is that my data structure is heavily nested. Example:

```
Company
  (to many) Person
    (to many) Property
      (to many) Network
        (to many) SubNetwork
```

I'm trying to create a full text search index for each `SubNetwork` that will display the current parent fields along side it.

Currently my data is completely denormalised, e.g:

```
{
    "company": "Coca-Cola",
    "property": "1 plaza hotel",
    "network": "ABC",
    "subNetwork": "123"
}
```

Now if a user were to go into the application and change the name of the company, right now (in the denormalized state), that would require Solr to partially update (atomic update) many documents which doesn't feel very efficient. Re-indexing the index isn't a preferred solution as this is a multi tenanted application.

I have tried putting the relational data in separate indexes and then used `join` within Solr but this does not copy over the joined indexes fields in the final result which means a full text search on all the fields isn't possible.

```
{!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}field:value
```

I'm trying to configure Solr in a way that when a parent record is updated, it only requires one atomic update but still retains the ability to search on all fields. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are seeing the performance issues, your initial implementation seems correct. Especially if you are returning subnetwork and may be searching on subnetwork and parent values at the same time.

Doing atomic update, under the covers, actually re-indexes the document anyway (and creates a Lucene-level new document). It also requires all fields to be stored to allow recreating the document. And the join reduces the scoring flexibility you can have.

One optimization you could do is to NOT store the parent fields, but keep them index-only. This will be more space-efficient and less disk/record re-hydration work. But then you cannot return those fields to the user and would have to fetch them from the original source instead.